# SQL Max Value only

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

In the following script I would like the `BH_StartDate` column to only return the highest date value as it presently returns all date values for all users. Is it possible to have only the Max date value with this script?

```
 SELECT         DISTINCT [dbo].[BH_Historic_Report_TaskAudit].BH_UserGuid       AS  'BighandUserGUID',
                BH_UserRole                                                     AS  'BighandUserRole',
                [dbo].[BH_Users].BH_FirstName                                   AS  'LastName',
                [dbo].[BH_Users].BH_Lastname                                    AS  'FirstName',
                [dbo].[BH_Users].BH_UserName                                    AS  'DisplayName',
                BH_StartDate                                                    AS  'StartDate', 
                [dbo].[BH_Users].BH_Description                                 AS  'JobDescription'

FROM            [dbo].[BH_Historic_Report_TaskAudit]
JOIN            [dbo].[BH_Users]
ON              [dbo].[BH_Historic_Report_TaskAudit].BH_UserGuid = [dbo].[BH_Users].BH_UserGuid
WHERE           BH_StartDate < '2015-04-29 00:00:00.000' AND BH_UserRole = 0 OR BH_UserRole = 2
ORDER BY        [dbo].[BH_Users].BH_LastName
```

Comment: Do you want the max date for each user or just 1 row that contains the max date from the entire result set?

Comment: consider using `AND BH_UserRole IN ( 0,  2 )`

Comment: Hello Harry  welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
  [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
   much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Right now isnt clear what is your desire result

Comment: Apologies for not being clear Juan. The desired result would display the max date for each user. Adding BH_UserRole IN ( 0, 2 ) as you have suggested has simplified the query and works well with Gadaju's script below. Thankyou kindly for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have first name and last name mixed in the column aliases. Also when you use both AND and OR in the where clause, you should parenthesis so as to avoid ambiguity about where the major conjuncts/disjuncts are.

My idea is to add a calculated column to BH_Historic_Report_TaskAudit to show the max BH_StartDate per user. It's fine to do the date filter at this point.
Then we join and filter for the roles we want and require that the BH_StartDate = max_BH_StartDate

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  hrt.BH_UserGuid AS 'BighandUserGUID',
  hrt.BH_UserRole  AS  'BighandUserRole',
  bu.BH_FirstName  AS 'LastName',
  bu.BH_Lastname  AS 'FirstName',
  bu.BH_UserName AS 'DisplayName',
  hrt.BH_StartDate AS 'StartDate', 
  bu.BH_Description AS 'JobDescription'
FROM (
      select 
        BH_UserGuid, BH_UserRole, BH_StartDate,
        max(BH_StartDate) over (partition by BH_UserGuid) max_BH_StartDate 
      from [dbo].[BH_Historic_Report_TaskAudit] 
      where BH_StartDate < '2015-04-29 00:00:00.000'
      ) hrt
JOIN [dbo].[BH_Users] bu
ON hrt.BH_UserGuid = bu.BH_UserGuid
WHERE 
  (hrt.BH_UserRole = 0 OR hrt.BH_UserRole = 2)
     and
   hrt.BH_StartDate = hrt.max_BH_StartDate
ORDER BY  bu.BH_LastName
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Gadaju this query works perfectly. Your clarity and assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create 2 #TempTable one for your all the records i.e. Master Table and create another table just to find the out MAX value from column. Then update the Column IN Master Table.